# How to get list of calendars in android with calendar IDs? Is it possible to get only calendars which are getting synced (non-local)?

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am not able to get list of calendar ids which can be synced (non local accounts). Also from that list, I wish to remove calendars such as Birthdays and Holidays and want the list of accounts where I can add user-specific events such as meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get the calendar id, the [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) can help you to get that all the calendar id from the user account. You can also view the calendar that are shared to your account. You can only filter the result of this if you use the `minAccessRole` parameter.

For the Holiday and Birthday part, I think you can only remove it by using the Calendar settings itself. **Settings** -> **Calendar**.

Comment: Thanks Kendi for the response. Can we use content provider to get only online calendars?